# Assign an address to a function pointer in a define in C

Tags: c

I want to assign an address to a function pointer in a define, is it possible? I want to do this in a define:

```
void (* uart_puts)(char *) = (void(*)(char * )) 0x0000000000008248;
char (* msg) = (char *) 0x7fb8;
```

Thanks!

Update:

Im compiling this function and I want to get both variables in a .h to simplify my .c file. I dont know if it's possible but ideally get these definitions in two define statements.

```
void function()
{
    void (* uart_puts)(char *) = (void(*)(char * )) 0x0000000000008248;
    char (* msg) = (char *) 0x7fb8;
    while (1)
    {
        uart_puts(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Defines are just "copy-paste" text with simple parameter text substitution. It is unclear how you are going to use your define macro, please clarify.

Comment: @hyde: Preprocessor macros substitute preprocessor tokens, not text.

Comment: Just use `static void (*uart_puts)(char *) = (void (*)(char*)) 0x0000000ffda;` in your header file.  Use `static` keyword, usually it is used with `const`.

Comment: Why the fixed addresses? Are you working in some embedded environment?

Comment: Ok, I update the info

Comment: You can also do `#define uart_puts ((void(*)(char*))0x000000008248)` and then `void f() { uart_puts("a"); }` will expand by the preprocessor.

Comment: I guess you are confusing others with the term *"define statement"*. `#define` is a C preprocessor directive, but I think you are asking about defining a global variable or something like that?

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks! Works perfectly

Comment: I think you get better results by using linker scripts, if not proper linking. That `uart_puts` comes from some other code. That code should be linkable, which would provide the address of it in a better, more standard way.

Comment: @ZanLynx The problem is that the code of `uart_puts` is running in other machine and what I want to do is compile this function resolving the address dependencies to send it to the machine and be able to run it

Comment: @KamilCuk That should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
#define uart_puts ((void(*)(char*))0x000000008248)
```

Then use it:

```
void f() { 
    uart_puts("a"); 
}
```

The text "uart_puts" will be exapnded by the preprocessor. Remember, that this means, that all symbols/texts "uart_puts" after the macro definition will be substituted.

But it would be better to store the information, that it's a function macro:

```
#define uart_puts(str)  ((void(*)(char*))0x000000008248)(str)
```

That way you can call `uart_puts(smth)`, but it's not possible to get the function pointer.

Also you can declare a `static` variable in your header file, usually with const:

```
static void (* const uart_puts)(char *) = (void (*)(char*)) 0x0000000ffda;
```

This is another way of declaring constants in header files in C, usually using compilers that the programmer knows, will optimize the static const variable and remove it, if it is unused.